# The CatAPI - Multiple Random Images for Javascript Object

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, infowindow, cat

The CatAPI is an API which will send you a random GIF of a cat each time you access it.

[The Cat API](http://thecatapi.com/api/images/get?format=src&type=gif)

It works like it is supposed to.  The issue is....I am using this in Google Maps.  I have many icons that show up on the screen, when you load the icon, it will load the event properties ("Name, blah etc") into the info window.  I have also given it a Cat Attribute which is the link to a random GIF (You may see where this is headed already)

The random cat gif ends up being the same gif for every InfoWindow (Even though the data is changing for each).

**[EDIT] I should clarify, the "data" that is changing is the City Name, Location...not the url for the Cat gif**

How do I resolve this random url http://thecatapi.com/api/images/get?format=src&type=gif to equal a specific image and apply that to my icons "cat" attribute.

Javascript Object getting cat attribute

```
if (results.list.length > 0) {
      resetData();
      for (var i = 0; i < results.list.length; i++) {
        results.list[i].imacat = "http://thecatapi.com/api/images/get?format=src&type=gif"
        geoJSON.features.push(jsonToGeoJson(results.list[i]));
      }
      drawIcons(geoJSON);
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Perhaps you need to provide a unique URL from the request to the Cat API so you don't get the same result from the cache.

Comment: Figured out the answer, thanks for your help anyways.  I answered below for completeness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well...it turns out I was making it harder in my head than I ever needed to....let this be a lesson to everyone.

Simple creating a timestamp variable at the end of the url allowed me to create an original request which the catapi could just dump off.

Example:

```js
var ts = new Date().getTime();
results.list[i].imacat = "http://thecatapi.com/api/images/get?format=src&type=gif&timestamp="+ts;
```

This creates something random on the end and I will get a bunch of objects with unique cat gifs!

Comment: This technique is called `cachebusting` and it isn't uncommon to name your param `cachebuster` or some such to indicate it isn't being used as an actual date value.

Comment: Thanks, I was not familiar with that term.  I learned something new